# Create Presence/Absence column in a data frame

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame that looks more or less like this

```
df <- tribble(
  ~Species, ~Symbiont, ~Location,
  "a",   "s01", "P01",
  "b",   "s02", "P01",
  "c",   "s01", "P02",
  "a",   "s03", "P03",
  "d",   "s02", "P02",
  "c",   "s04", "P04",
  "a",   "s03", "P01",
  "c",   "s02", "P02",
  "c",   "s03", "P02"
)
```

What I'd like to to achieve is to have a single row for each `Species` in each `Location`, and a presence-absence 0-1 info about the `Symbiont`.

For example, with the given data,

```
Species s01  s02  s03  s04 Location
   a     1    0    1    0    P01
   a     0    0    1    0    P03
   b     0    1    0    0    P02
   c     1    1    1    0    P02
   c     0    0    0    1    P04
   d     0    1    0    0    P02
```

I'd like to use tidyverse as I'm more comfortable with it but whatever works

I'll spare you the goofy attempt I've tried...

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, add a presence/absence indicator to your tibble.  As you only have "presence"s to start with, every value will be `1`

```
df %>% add_column(Present=1)
```

Now use `pivot_wider` to untidy your data

```
df %>% 
  add_column(Present=1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=Symbiont, values_from=Present)
```

Finally, replace the `NA`s we've introduced, which correspond to absences, with `0`s.

```
df %>% 
  add_column(Present=1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=Symbiont, values_from=Present) %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0)
```

Giving

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  Species Location   s01   s02   s03   s04
  <chr>   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a       P01          1     0     1     0
2 b       P01          0     1     0     0
3 c       P02          1     1     1     0
4 a       P03          0     0     1     0
5 d       P02          0     1     0     0
6 c       P04          0     0     0     1
```

Comment: There is `values_fill` in `pivot_wider` which will help to remove the last step with `replace`.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful! However, in case of two rows which are exactly the same (can happen, my bad for not putting it in the example) `pivot_wider` will output lists.
To avoid that I just created a unique identifier by adding row number: `mutate(row = row_number())`
and removing it at the end `select(-row)`

Comment: Yep,  That will work.

Comment: Sorry, after better testing seems like adding a row number and then removing does only give a single `1` per row. Best solution I found was to work with `distinct(df)` instead of `df`, in order to remove all duplicate rows (which, being a binary matrix, are totally redundant anyway

Answer (score 4):

Here is a base R option using `replace`

```
replace(
  u <- reshape(cbind(df, Presence = 1),
    direction = "wide",
    idvar = c("Species", "Location"),
    timevar = "Symbiont"
  ),
  is.na(u),
  0
)
```

such that

```
  Species Location Presence.s01 Presence.s02 Presence.s03 Presence.s04
1       a      P01            1            0            1            0
2       b      P01            0            1            0            0
3       c      P02            1            1            1            0
4       a      P03            0            0            1            0
5       d      P02            0            1            0            0
6       c      P04            0            0            0            1
```